# ASP.NET MVC ExecuteResult vs ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, streaming

I'v seen it used to add headers to the response and then return a file for streaming.

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    ...
        response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", responseLength.ToString());
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public); //required for etag output
        response.Cache.SetETag(etag); //required for IE9 resumable downloads
        response.ContentType = blockBlob.Properties.ContentType;

        blockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream(response.OutputStream, startIndex, responseLength);
}
```

What's the difference in using `ExecuteResult` vs `ActionResult` and how would you make it Async?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteResult` is the one and only abstract method of `ActionResult`. It is this method that is executed by the MVC framework after the action method returns in order to produce the output to the browser.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public abstract class ActionResult
    {
        public abstract void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context);
    }
}
```

So, there literally is no difference between the two - returning any `ActionResult` subclass tells the MVC framework to execute the `ExecuteResult` method on that class.

If using MVC 5, there is no way to run it Async. However, the [MVC Core `ActionResult` class](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/custom-actionresult-aspnet5-mvc6) contains an `ExecuteResultAsync` method.

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteResult` is an abstract method on `ActionResult`.  `ActionResult` is the base class for any result returned from an ASP.NET MVC controller, other than the built in data types within C#.

If you are implementing `ExecuteResult` it is probably a custom implementation for a result.

This is explained within the `ActionResult.ExecuteResult` documentation on [this documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.executeresult(v=vs.118).aspx), it says the following:

> (Method ExecuteResult) Enables processing of the result of an action method by a custom type that inherits from the ActionResult class.

Comment: "If you are implementing ExecuteResult it is probably a custom implementation for a result." this is the key point.